# Java 8 poor GUI performance compared to Java 6

Tags: java, performance, swing, user-interface, java-8

In Java 6 below code is running as expected but in Java 8 it is taking much more time. The interesting part is that components use the same method `setEnable()` for enabling and disabling components, but the disabling call takes much longer than the enabling one, almost twice as much. Disabling in Java 8 is taking much longer than the one in Java 1.6. The question is why does this happen? Is this a performance problem of Java 8?

Here are the results for Java 6:

```
    Sun Microsystems Inc. 1.6.0_45
    Initializing GUI
    GUI initialized in 1105 ms
    Disabling
    Disabled in 687 ms
    Enabling
    Enabled in 375 ms
```

Here are the results for Java 8:

```
    Oracle Corporation 1.8.0_25
    Initializing GUI
    GUI initialized in 604 ms
    Disabling
    Disabled in 6341 ms
    Enabling
    Enabled in 370 ms
```

The code:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class TestGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public TestGUI() {
        initGUI();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String text;
        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Enable-ALL")){
            enableAll();
            text= "Disable-ALL";
        }
        else{
            disableAll();
            text= "Enable-ALL";
        }
        ((JButton)e.getSource()).setText(text);
        ((JButton)e.getSource()).setEnabled(true);

    }


    private  void initGUI() {
        long m = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Initializing GUI");
        setTitle(System.getProperty("java.vendor") + " " + System.getProperty("java.version"));
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JButton b = new JButton("Disable-ALL ");
        b.addActionListener(this);
        add(b);

        for (int i = 1; i < 10001; i++) {
            b = new JButton("Button " + i);
            add(b);
        }
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(600, 600);
        setVisible(true);
        m = System.currentTimeMillis() - m;
        System.out.println("GUI initialized in " + m + " ms");
    }

    private void disableAll() {
        long m = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Disabling");
        for (Component c : getContentPane().getComponents()) {
            c.setEnabled(false);
        }

        m = System.currentTimeMillis() - m;
        System.out.println("Disabled in " + m + " ms");
    }

    private void enableAll() {
        long m = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Enabling");
        for (Component c : getContentPane().getComponents()) {
            c.setEnabled(true);
            invalidate();
        }
        m = System.currentTimeMillis() - m;
        System.out.println("Enabled in " + m + " ms");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.vendor") + " "
                        + System.getProperty("java.version"));
                new TestGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not the way to measure performance for Java applications. Currently you include class loading time costs which only occur once. Use JMH library for micro benchmarks

Comment: Yes you are right this is not a benchmark.. However As a user I can feel the slowness. As you can see in Java 1.8 disabling is in 6341 ms while enabling is 370 ms. They are using same method setEnable(). Why this is happened?

Comment: 6 seconds is a lot of time - do you get similar figures if you run it a few times?

Comment: @Vic I agree with mbsau in one thing. You can have all the metrics in the world, but at the end of the day, your system is only as good as the user perceives it to be.

Comment: Yes I got.  Some sample are Disabled in 6159 ms..Enabled in 372 ms ## 
Disabled in 5926 ms..Enabled in 358 ms ##
Disabled in 6147 ms..Enabled in 576 ms

Comment: You're right, apologies. I've missed that 6 seconds measurement as I've skipped the code. It is weird and interesting to look into

Comment: Could it be related to the absence of a call to `invalidate` in disableAll function?

Comment: When the invalidate() method calls the results are same :( Actually in my first attempts it was there.

Comment: case is same with java 8-40 ea and java 9-ea

Comment: Profile it ......................

Answer (score 26):

According to my profiler, the operation spends most of the time in the method `Thread.holdsLock`, which can be indeed a costly operation, which is called by `Component.checkTreeLock` which is called indirectly by `Component.updateCursorImmediately`.

Generally, you can avoid costly visual updates when updating multiple components by calling `getContentPane().setVisible(false);` right before the operation and `getContentPane().setVisible(true);` right afterwards, e.g.

```
private void disableAll() {
    long m = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Disabling");
    getContentPane().setVisible(false);
    for (Component c : getContentPane().getComponents()) {
        c.setEnabled(false);
    }
    getContentPane().setVisible(true);

    m = System.currentTimeMillis() - m;
    System.out.println("Disabled in " + m + " ms");
}
```

You will see, such problems will vanish, regardless of which kind of visual update causes the problem in detail.

So you don’t need to think about how to benchmark correctly here, not that it matters when the operation takes seconds, but I recommend learning the difference between `System.currentTimeMillis()` and [`System.nanoTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime--) as the latter is the right tool for measuring *elapsed time*.

Comment: thanks Holger. In our application there is no number of components in a view as above code sample. This small code peace reproduce our gui performance problem. 
Our actual problem is that when the component's updates itself(or Frame) after data which is to be displayed gets from server. Data is getting from server by asynchronized way. Maybe more than one  data fetch requests go to the server when Frames initialize. So there is no certain point to getContentPane().setVisible() methods in these situations. Do I realy need to change codes? Because It is working good at java 1.6.

Comment: You may file a bug report to Oracle for a performance problem of this magnitude. But even if it is fixed in the next version you have to decide how to handle users using the version affected by the problem. For me it’s not the first time that an update turn a previously simple operation into a lengthy one, that can happen even in a minor update. So the bad news is, GUI programming is work-around programming. I don’t know enough about your application to give more specific advice. But if you get an asynchronous event you have to put some action on the EDT at one point so you’ve control over it…

Comment: 1. AWT/Swing is ignored by Oracle from takeover of Java from Sun, 2. graphics algorithm, rendering logics is prehistorics, 3. core is optimized for todays JavaFX with near to todays rendering logics and quite good optimalizations for GPU (in all cases better than possible by using AWT/Swing APIs), 4. here is a few semi bugs correspondings with missing optimalizations for part of old APIs

Comment: @mKorbel: We tried JavaFX for some real-life tasks and dropped it as a bad joke right after the tests. I can’t understand why these developers like that scene graph concept that already failed with Java3D and Java Media Framework. The problem is not that JavaFX had much more bugs than AWT/Swing (in crucial parts) but that you can’t even work around these bugs as you can’t perform any action not foreseen by the FX developers (and apparently they have a very narrow view). Well, if you like to make the non-working UI look beautiful using CSS, there you go…

Comment: @Holger good points with interesting facts (thin client doesn't required beautiful non-working UI look, somehow, most times to blind for Key and Mouse events, "based on whatever"), anyway thanks

Answer (score 5):

I haven't had a chance to understand exactly, but it seems like event handling might have changed in 8. Disabling the parent first speeds up the process:

```
getContentPane().setEnabled(false);
for (Component c : getContentPane().getComponents()) {
    c.setEnabled(false);
}
getContentPane().setEnabled(true);
```