# javaws.exe poor performance compared with java.exe in java8

Tags: java, performance, profiling, java-8, java-web-start

You have to contract for supporting non public available Java releases with Oracle for example Java6 ended with 1.6.0_45 publicly but with support you can use 1.6.0_80. Our aim is to stay supported and public available java platform. Therefore we want to migrate our jnlp based RIA application from Java6 to java8 platform. In migration testing we have experienced performance problem. We try to simulate this problem in [Java 8 poor GUI performance compared to Java 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28046809/java-8-poor-gui-performance-compared-to-java-6) but we realize that the problem not related the that question.

After the introduction, in order to find out the root cause of problem we profiled the application with java mission control(jmc) bundled with jdk. when we profile application launched at workspace we cannot see any performance degradation. And then we realize that problem occurs only JAVAWS environment. Our application runs as expected at java environment but in javaws environment some GUI's are really slow , it adds 6 seconds more to response time.

**My first question is that how we profile java application launched by javaws?** Because to use jmc we need to set some JVM arguments (`java-vm-args="-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder"`) but javaws doesn't support this JVM parameters. You can find supported list at [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#resources)

**My Second question is that why application doesn't run identical at both environment(java and javaws)?** We examined signed and unsigned version of our application and both have same situation. By the way our application uses `all-permission`.

Comment: Just form completeness, if you use a profiler like `JVisualVM` instead (included in the jdk as well), you don’t need any command line options; it can simply attach to a Java process already running locally on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass any JVM arguments you want to javaws by typing them in:
Java Control Panel > Java > View > Runtime Parameters

As for the poor performance, are you referring to application load time? or is it also slow after the applicatio is started?

If you're talking about load time, then yes javaws is slower (about 3-5 seconds slower) because it has to contact Internet to check if your jar files are black listed or if the certificate is expired. I'm not sure exactly what it is doing in these few seconds but I agree that it is disappointing performance hit and I hope someone can shed more light on it.

Comment: At initialization yes there is a slowness. But our problem also occurs after initialization. Especially when the document viewer is opened its taking long time. in the viewer there are lots resource loading e.g. icons and a lot awt event . if i back to office i will try your suggestion.

Comment: You can see exactly what webstart is doing when the document viewer is opened. You can see this in Java Console (make sure Show Java Console is selected in Java Control Panel). But first you need to add deployment.trace.level=all to this file: C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties

Comment: To test profiling at home I tried to pass mentioned JVM args but application didn't start. Without passing params application can start. So I couldn't profile my application again. I can see at log -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder could be parsed but final java command  -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures removed. And final log is "basic: Exiting".. I will try your second suggestion at office.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Saeid. Problem is determined. We profiled finally and we found that javaws consume long time to load resources e.g. icons, images. to make a solution we cached the resources and for absence images we return a empty image.

You can see this at [image: profiling result]

To profile application  launched by javaws we make a solution following steps in ubuntu

```
1. move java executable javam
2. create a script file named java and insert following script 
   #!/bin/bash
   /full/path/of/javam XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder "$@"
3. run application and check java is launched by ps -ef | grep javam
4. run jmc and profile it.
```

Comment: Doesn't javaws automatically cache the resources already? So how much improvement in performance did you get after this change? curious

Comment: Our util class cache images resources in a hasmap. Firstly look into hashmap if not available it loads with class.getrosurces method. Javaws doesnt cache this type resources as much as i understand. After this 10 seconds startup screen open under 1 second. By the way Our word processor was trying to load 200 missing icons. After changing Of resources from gif to png and changing of loading mechanizm developer missed out to delete ex code. So there is unnecessary code's call in our application. We fixed this fault and problem went away